# Interpolation function in processing

Tags: arrays, mouseevent, processing, linear-interpolation, lerp

I am new new to processing and I am trying to experiment with the `lerp` function in processing. Basically what I am trying to do is, click on different point on the screen, these positions are being stored in an array. when the user clicks `enter`, the stored movements are replayed with an `ellipse` moving smoothly between the points. My problem is that when I click enter, I am getting the 'Arithmetic exception by zero'. Can you please guide me what I am missing? Thanks.

```java
final static int numFrames = 30; //frames between keyframes
final static int numKeyFrames = 1; //frames between keyframes
Point[] keyFrames;
Point[] frames;

void setup()  
{
  size(640, 480);
  frameRate(30);
  LinearInterp();
}

void mouseClicked()
{
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(8);
  for(int i=0; i<numKeyFrames; i++)
  {
    keyFrames = new Point[numKeyFrames];
    keyFrames[i] = new Point(mouseX,mouseY);
    point(keyFrames[i].x,keyFrames[i].y);
    println("Mouse Coordinates are: " + keyFrames[i]);
  }
}

void LinearInterp() 
{
  frames = new Point[numFrames*(numKeyFrames-1)]; 
  for (int kf = 0; kf< numKeyFrames-1; kf++)
  {
    Point p0 = keyFrames[kf];
    Point p1 = keyFrames[kf+1];
    for (int f =0; f<numFrames; f++)
    {
      float a = f*1.0/numFrames;
      int newX = int(p0.x * (1-a) + p1.x * a);
      int newY = int(p0.y * (1-a) + p1.y * a);
      frames[f+(kf*numFrames)] = new Point(newX,newY);
    }
  }
}

void animateFrames()
{
  stroke(187);
  strokeWeight(10);
  int i = frameCount % frames.length;  
  point(frames[i].x,frames[i].y);
}

void drawFrames() 
{
  stroke(187);
  strokeWeight(2);
  for (int i=0; i<frames.length; i++)
  {
    point(frames[i].x,frames[i].y);
  }
}

void draw() 
{
  if(keyPressed)
  {
    if(key == ENTER)
    {
      drawFrames();
      animateFrames();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you delete [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466339/interpolation-technique-in-processing)? Please don't delete questions after somebody takes the time to answer them.

Like I said in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466339/interpolation-technique-in-processing), you need to store the index of which "leg" of the journey you're on. You also need to store how far along that leg the point should be. When you reach the next point, then increment the index and reset the percentage.

In any case, you need to break this problem down into smaller steps. Can you create a program that shows a circle travelling from one hard-coded point to another? Start with that, without worrying about user input. Get that working perfectly before moving on. Then get a program working that shows a circle moving from a hard-coded point to a point the user clicks. Get that working perfectly. Then get a program that shows a circle moving between two user clicks. Get that working perfectly. Notice a pattern?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i really appreciate, I tried working it out, but i am having a arithmetic exception by zero.

Comment: @user3157072 If you have follow-up questions, please create a [mcve] (this should be a single circle moving from one point to another, without any extra code) in a new post and we'll go from there. Good luck.